# Dereferencing a reference not working

Tags: c++, pointers, vector, reference

I have a function that returns the median of a vector:

```
unsigned int Class::Median() const {    
    sort(m_Transactions.begin(), m_Transactions.end(), cmpInt);

    if (m_Transactions.size() != 0) {
        if ( m_Transactions.size()%2 == 0 ) {
            return *m_Transactions[ m_Transactions.size()/2 + 1 ];
        } else {
            return *m_Transactions[ m_Transactions.size()/2 ];
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

The vector is `vector<unsigned int> m_Transactions`. As I understand, the `[]` operator returns a reference to the element from array. I don't want to return a reference but the element. So I dereference with `*`. Compilator error states: `invalid type argument of unary '*'...`.

However, if I remove the '*':

```
if ( m_Transactions.size()%2 == 0 ) {
    return m_Transactions[ m_Transactions.size()/2 + 1 ];
} else {
    return m_Transactions[ m_Transactions.size()/2 ];
}
```

The build fails due to `assignment of read-only location...`

Rest of the code [HERE](http://pastebin.com/XsgG9DkT).

How do I solve this? And why is the dereference not working?

Comment: You can't dereference a reference, unless it's a reference to a pointer. Simply use what the [] operator gives you back as if it were a value. And read a good C++ text book.

Comment: Your first return will probably cause an error: if size == 2, size / 2 + 1 = 2

Comment: Remove the `const` from the function and see if works....

Comment: Removing `const` fixed the issue, thank you very much. However, due to the assignment, the `const` has to be there.

Comment: Well then, you have to copy `m_transactions` to a new variable, and sort that one instead and get the median from it, since sort modifies the thing it sorts.

Comment: Of course, that makes sense.

Comment: Note that this is really two questions. One about dereferencing the reference (answer: you don't). Once you fix that, you uncover a new problem about `const`ness. That problem is unrelated to the original problem. It's just that the first problem was so bad it prevented the compiler from seeing the second one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do **NOT** need to **dereference** using `*`. The `operator[]` index already **dereferences** the value in std::vector for you.

See below:

### Update

```
std::vector<unsigned int> ret = m_Transactions; // Use auxiliary ret vector to return while maintaining the const in your function signature.
std::sort(ret.begin(), ret.end(), cmpInt);
if (ret.size() != 0) {
    if (ret.size()%2 == 0 ) {
        return ret[ ret.size()/2 + 1 ]; // remove the * dereference operator
    } else {
        return ret[ ret.size()/2 ];  // remove the * dereference operator
    }
}
```

Comment: If I do that, the build fails due to `assignment of read-only location...`

Comment: @HichigayaHachiman the code you provided has no assignments  (var a = x). The error must be coming from **elsewhere**.

Comment: Remove the **const** at the end of your function signature.

Comment: That worked, unfortunately the assignment doesn't allow me to remove it. Any workaround? I've also edited rest of the code.

Comment: Try it now...this is a workaround for the const function.

Comment: I used `vector<unsigned int> copy (m_Transactions);` instead but yes, it worked, thank you.